# No, you already after school

Tags: grammar

He picked him up after school.

At afternoon, he wanted to go to school.

> "**No, you already after school.**"

How do we say no school or completed school day already?

Comment: "No, you've already finished school for today" or "No, school's over for today".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence begins OK, but it has no verb.  Every English sentence has to have a verb.

**No, you...**

There are a few possibilities we could use.

**...already went to school today.** This is what I would use.

**...finished school today.**

**...are already done with school for today.**